Connect from Spring Boot app in Cloud Run to Postgres in Cloud Sql instance using IAM
I get an error connecting from Cloud Run to Cloud Sql using IAM and cloud sql auth proxy:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.
I have a Spring boot Rest WebServices app deployed in Cloud Run.
The Postgres database in Cloud SQL is using private IP and has IAM authentication enabled (the database flag cloudsql.iam_authentication=on)
I want my app to connect from Cloud Run the database using IAM authetication, with service account
Application.properties looks like this:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///${DB_NAME}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=30
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useSSL=false


The service account has the roles Cloud SQL Client, Cloud SQL Editor, Cloud SQL Instance User
In the database I defined the user like this (sercice account name without the suffix .gserviceaccount.com):
create user "...@....iam" with login;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "aaa" TO "...@....iam";


The application's docker image is deployed like this:

gcloud run deploy xxxx --image gcr.io/yyy/zzz --platform managed  --region europe-west1 --set-env-vars DB_NAME=aaa --set-env-vars DB_USERNAME=sss@xxxx.iam  --set-env-vars INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=.... --add-cloudsql-instances ... --service-account ...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com

When connecting using database username/password everything works fine.
I tried adding &enableIamAuth=true to database URL, no change.

For Spring Boot I would recommend checking out the spring-cloud-gcp support for Postgres connections: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.3.0/reference/html/index.html#cloud-sql-iam-database-authentication
